# Check if string contains specific characters- Validation Rule

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I have a field text that cannot contain either l m or p whether it is upper or lower case. How can I accomplish this in a validation rule?

Please give examples. Perhaps a regular expression example or if there are functions that can be used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex formula will work in a validation rule:

```
REGEX(Field__c, ".*[lLmMpP].*")
```

It says the field can start with any character, contain the letters you don't want and then end with any character.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression would look like this: `/[lmp]/gixm`. Here's a very [handy utility](http://www.regexr.com/v1/) for determining regular expressions which is courtesy of [GSkinner](http://www.regexr.com/). You didn't say whether the field was rich text or not, so I've included flags that assumed it was.

Here's a link to [Useful Validation Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulValidationRules.meta/usefulValidationRules/fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm) which should provide you with plenty of examples to help you figure out how to implement the rest of what you need. I know it contains some Regex examples.

Comment: It's a regular text field.

Comment: If it's not multi-line, then you could drop the "m" and just use `/[lmp]/gix`. I highly recommend you try the links I gave you so you can play with the utility to learn how to do this yourself.